# How to compress both files and folders with ZipFile API

Tags: c#, compression, zip

I want to compress Zip to be same structure with folder.
but, ZipFile API seems unable to compress folder.

How to compress these folder structure?

The following code can't compress folder itself.

```
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(Path.Combine(m_strWorkingDirectory, "build.zip"), ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach( string path in m_listTargetPath )
    {
        string strPath = Path.Combine(m_strWorkingDirectory, path);
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(strPath, path);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you just need ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

Comment: @andyb952 ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory couldn't compress files of folder-in-folder. I want same structure and same files.

Answer (score 0):

If ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory() doesn't do what you need (I thought it would) then you can just get all the files/folders you need and add them in using an extension method:

```
public static class FileExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> AllFilesAndFolders(this DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        foreach (var f in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            yield return f;
        }

        foreach (var d in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            yield return d;
            foreach (var o in AllFilesAndFolders(d))
            {
                yield return o;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then using your same format, you should be able to do something like so (not tested):

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(m_strWorkingDirectory);
using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(Path.Combine(m_strWorkingDirectory, "build.zip"), ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    foreach (FileInfo file in dir.AllFilesAndFolders().Where(o => o is FileInfo).Cast<FileInfo>())
    {
        var relPath = file.FullName.Substring(dir.FullName.Length + 1);
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, relPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: @dubs did my answer help you out your issue in the end?